# How do I reinstantiate my Steps class before each JBehave story?

Tags: jbehave

My JBehave executor extends `JUnitStories` to load and run several `.story` files. It overrides the `stepsFactory` method as seen in many examples throughout the web:

```
public class JBehaveTest extends JUnitStories {

    @Override
    public InjectableStepsFactory stepsFactory() {
        return new InstanceStepsFactory(configuration(), new MySteps());
    }
```

`MySteps` is a POJO that implements the @Given, @When, @Then annotated step methods. It keeps state in internal members to keep track of what happened in When to be able to assert correctly in Then. For example:

```
public class Steps {

    private Response response;

    @When("I post this and that")
    public void whenIPostThisAndThat() {
        this.response = sendRestRequest();
    }

    @Then("I get an OK response")
    public void thenIGetAnOKResponse() {
        assertThat(response.httpStatus).isEqualTo("200");
    }
```

When designing this, I had expected JBehave to reinstantiate `MySteps` before it starts the next story, so the state is reset. Unfortunately, this doesn't happen. The `stepsFactory` method is called exactly once before all stories are run, and the `InstanceStepsFactory` keeps the one instance of `MySteps` alive across all stories. As a result I get carryover errors from one story to the next.

What's the best way to force JBehave to reinstantiate the `MySteps` class before the next story?

Comment: Use annotations such as @BeforeStories and/or @BeforeStory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@BeforeStory` solves it. At least good enough for me. It doesn't reinstantiate the `Steps` class, but at least gives you a hook where you can reset internal state. Praise goes to [Bill Hileman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5749062/bill-hileman):

```
public class Steps {

    private Response response;

    @BeforeStory
    public void resetContext() {
        response = null;
    }
```

Comment: Glad I could help.